# Workflow History on a Form Library: how to view previous versions of an edited form?

Tags: workflow, form, library

Is it possible to get hyperlinks to previous versions of a form, or even just see a list of changes to a Form Library item via Workflow History? If that wouldn't be available, what are the workarounds? So far what I can think of is to manually write column data to another list using a workflow anytime something is changed on the Form Library's items, but if there are any easier strategies, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can enable versioning on list. So you can view all changes in item history.

Will this suite your scenario?

Comment: That should probably work also. I checked and it looks like Form Libraries can also have versioning: http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2012/10/version-control-infopath-forms-templates-sharepoint-libraries/ Thanks for the suggestion.